# mixing 5.1 in a small studio ?

Tags: 5.1, mixing, small, studio

I have the experience of Dolby digital mixing for songs in my decently big film school studio.We have big industry standards JBL speakers for LCR and 3 to 4 LS and RS speakers each ( called pulz).
Few days back i was asked by a studio guy to make a 5.1 song mix in a comparatively small studio with small Genelec speakers as LCR and 1 speaker each for LS and RS.Am doubtful about its output in big theater and bit concerned about the amount of reverb and delay that i should assign.Also will it be wise & worth to take up the task?

Answer (score 1):

It can be done, you should start by reading this:

http://duc.avid.com/showthread.php?t=87830

John.